# Ways to handle exceptions like WebClientRequestException due to service unavailability for all calls from a WebClient instance than individually

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

As the title suggests, I'm using Spring WebClient to invoke an external api and process the response. I have added a **ExchangeFilterFunction** to handle the response based on the status code returned from the server as something like below.

```java
ExchangeFilterFunction responseProcessor() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(response -> {
        if (response.statusCode().isError()) {
            return Mono.error(new RuntimeException("WebClient Error"));
        }
        return Mono.just(response);
    });
}
```

Now, this works fine with services that return a response for the request when it is up. But when the service is down, the request fails with **WebClientRequestException** which is fine but the error thrown is not handled by the *responseProcessor* and gets propagated.

I'm aware that the error can be handled on the *WebClient* call using any of the *onErrorXXX* methods. But if we use that *WebClient* instance to make many calls across different parts of the code, the handling looks inefficient. So, I'd like to know whether there's a way to handle this error for all calls done by that *webclient* instance instead of handling it in all of individual invocations. Something like what the *responseProcessor* does for all responses.

Comment: did you read the spring webflux official documentation on how to handle responses, as handling responses in the way you are doing it is not the recommended way according to the documentation.

Comment: here is a link to the spring reference docs - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-retrieve

Answer (score 2):

when you use .exchangeToMono() or .exchangeToFlux() methods it will give you back a mono or flux .
there is an interesting method on mono or flux which is transform() .
transform take a function an add it to your flux or mono chain.

you can define a chain as a function anywhere and use this chain many time in different chains.

so define your exception handling chain ( by using onError() method ) as a function and after you get your response by exchangeToMono() or exchangeToFlux() , use .transform method and pass your exception handling chain to it.

any way , there is another way too .
you can create a method which is your proxy to call any external resource , which use webClient in itself.
then you can apply AOP pattern to it and handle exception in this way.

Comment: can you please provide code examples and links to any relevant documentation